# Access query grid count rows only if two fields have the same value

Tags: ms-access, relational-database

How do I count only rows where a pilot has flown out of and in from a departure airport and destination airport. For example if a pilot has flown from LHR to HKG and from HKG to LHr but not include a pilot who has flown to HKG from LHR but not flown back to HKG?

Example

[image]

We see that **AC00060** has flown from HKG to LHR and further down we see **AC00060** has flown from LHR to HKG. This pilot may have done this multiple times.

**Question:** In an Access query grid not sql how do I find and count rows that A_Code and D_code match for one pilot by payroll_num and count how many times that occurs for each pilot?

Comment: Select a.*, b.* from [your table] a inner join [your table] b on a.D_Code=b.A_Code

Comment: What do the stars mean? All column a and all column b? Is this in the query grid? It reads like Sql which what I know how to do already?

Comment: @TimothyLawman - What do you mean "in the query grid"?  Gavin is proposing a new query based on what you've shown above.

Comment: are you trying to find the number of pilots did at least one round trip, or are you trying to find the number of round trips each pilot did? you may create a math function.

Comment: @TimothyLawman The stars mean everything from those tables which as you know how to do SQL already you know. If you know SQL then I suggest you ditch the query design window and use the SQL window instead to write your query. Unless of course that's not what you mean by `in the query grid`. I was simply quickly trying to point you in the direction of something which you could play around with and figure out yourself.

Comment: Guys I am trying to do this only in MS Access as that is what is required. I can do it in SQL myself. The query grid is Ms Access' way of doing queries.

Comment: I am trying to: count  the number of round trips each pilot did?

Comment: Timothy, I don't know whether your deliberately being obtuse or not. MS Access Query Design window has an SQL pane. If you look at the top left corner when in a query design, you will see a button with a drop down on it. Click the drop down, and there's an option for SQL. If you know the sql you would write, then enter it here (paying attention to the JET format for join parentheses etc), switch back to the design view and you will get the `query grid` you seem so obsessed with.

Comment: I know this but on some syllabus you must use the query grid a sspecified in the window - I have solved it this way

Comment: Do a count duplicates query instead of basic query and use totals with count  on the answer, it can also be done using grand totals in cross-tab. Sorry to seem obtuse but the question was specified in this way and examiners report said almost no one could do it.I will  post my query grid soon.

Answer (score 0):

Method: Do a count duplicates query in the Access Query wizard,then do a sum on the NumDupelicates field and divide by 2 to get each round trip.

[image: Access Query grid view]

Comment: Apologies to people using SWL for your time but I did specify both in the tags and question it was an Ms Access query.

Comment: Yes, well, on a programming answers website there isn't going to be a "real world" need to **not** use SQL in this case.  Notice the lack of a "query" or "query-grid" tag available?